# The html format of the content printed to the screen

Tags: html

There is a parameter named content in the result returned from Whois Api. When I reflect the parameter named Content to the screen with html, the text is written side by side. I am trying to do this as in Whois in website How can I do it? Please your help.

My html output

[image]

Value from API

[image]

In Whois webside

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in the `<pre>` tag to preserve the new line characters.